# Unwittingly download same file from AWS S3 Bucket using boto3.client("s3",<AWS_Credentials>).download_file(params)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download a specific file using API call in Python3. I pass three params viz:

```
BucketName; fileObjectKey (in S3 Bucket), ServerName
```

I have file **abcd123.pdf** stored in S3 bucket in a AWS cloud named as Development. I have another AWS cloud named as Production where I don't have this file.
But, I download same file when I change ServerName from "development" to "production" which have different AWS credentials altogether.
My API call urls are:

```
localhost:5005/apicall?BucketName=bucket111&FileObjectkey=input/abcd123.pdf&ServerName=development
localhost:5005/apicall?BucketName=bucket111&FileObjectkey=input/abcd123.pdf&ServerName=production
```

Here I download same file "abcd123.pdf" even when there is no such file in Production server. Only I could not when I change the BucketName or FileObjectKey

I use following function to download the file from S3 bucket.

```
def download_resumes_s3Bucket_PostMethod(BucketName, FileObjectKey, ServerName):  
     try:
            if ServerName == "development":
                aws_access_key_id = "development@@Key0000011"
                aws_secret_access_key = "development@@SecretAccessKey0000012"
            elif ServerName == "production":
                aws_access_key_id = "production@@Key0000022"
                aws_secret_access_key = "production@@SecretAccessKey0000023"

            s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

            destination_folder = "../localFolder"

            if FileObjectKey.split(".")[-1] in ("pdf", "docx", "doc"):
                s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, FileObjectKey, os.path.join(destination_folder, s3object_key.split("/")[-1]))
            else:
                raise Exception


        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
```

**Note:** They (*Development* and *Production* are two different AWS accounts, therefore two different AWS credentials

Comment: What do you mean by development and Production here? DIfferent AWS accounts? Do you have two buckets with same in two different accounts?

Comment: They are two different AWS accounts, therefore two different AWS credentials.

Comment: The Bucket names must be different. You cannot create two buckets with same name across AWS.

Comment: I agree, but I want to know why it downloads again when I switch to ServerName keeping other two params same. I should get error of not finding bucket

Comment: Yes, unless your bucket/object is public or has a bucket policy or ACL that allows the other account to read the object?

Comment: If file is made public then it cud be downloaded without credentials too? Because in my case file was made public in AWS-S3 bucket.

Comment: That is what is happening. It is not throwing any error when accessing with wrong credentials because the object is public. It can be downloaded without any valid credentials.